# lubuntu 14.10 gedit plugin folder

Tags: lubuntu, gedit, plugins

Which directory should I copy gedit plugins for gedit to recognize them in? I was browsing around the web, none of proposed folders worked. I want to use ftp code editng gedit plugin.

Comment: have you tried the system-wide plug-in directory? `/usr/share/gedit/plugins`

Comment: Yes, I have, it does not work

Comment: Have you tried another plugin?  maybe this particular plugin isn't compatible with your version of gedit?

Comment: @Fabby, I am trying to install gedit-ftp-browser at https://code.google.com/p/gedit-ftp-browser/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a plugin for gedit 2 and not compatible with gedit 3.

I tried downloading it, putting it in the right (3.0) directory, changing the interpreter from python to python3 and upgrading the version to 3 but it still didn't work...

Therefore, the solution is: contact the developer for a new version.

(Probably not what you wanted to hear, but alas)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the grey check-mark to turn it green.  Better then posting "thank you" for the work I did!  ;-)